# Как в тексте после каждой 3-5 точки вставить /n ?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Пытаюсь регуляркой написать такой трюк:
В тексте (строке) надо после каждой 3-5(выбираться должно случайно) найденной точки вставлять после точки перенос строки (или /n)

Затравка:

```
$a='фовр. hasgdjashgd. dahsgdjahs ashdg aj. ashgjdag.  jashgdjashd.asdasd.asdasd.asd.as.d.';
$b=preg_replace('/.../','...',$a);
```

Comment: У вас тоже интересные варианты, но я искал свой, вот что у меня получилось, покритикуйте пожалуйста, если не лень.

    function getRandom($n){
  $r=rand(-50,10); // тут вероятность регулируется
  if ($r>=0) {$out="$n\n";}
  else {$out=$n;}
  echo $out;
  return $out;
  }
    $in=preg_replace('/([\.\!\?]+)/e',"getRandom('$1')",$in);

Функцию нужно в одну строку написать тренарником, сыровато конечно

Answer (score 2):

```
function addNL($s){
    $b = '';
    $sp = rand(3,5);
    for($i = 0, $il = strlen($s); $i < $il;++$i){
        $b .= $s[$i];
        if($s[$i] == '.'){
            --$sp;
            if(!$sp){
                $b .= '<br>';
                $sp = rand(3,5);
            }
        }
    }
    return $b;
}
```

И потом одной строкой:

```
$a = 'фовр. hasgdjashgd. dahsgdjahs ashdg aj. ashgjdag.  jashgdjashd.asdasd.asdasd.asd.as.d.';
echo addNL($a);
```

Comment: ну это чит :) Но и по другому нельзя...

Comment: Почему? Можно.

    function addNL($s){$b='';$sp=rand(3,5);for($i=0,$il=strlen($s);$i<$il;++$i){$b.=$s[$i];if($s[$i]=='.'){--$sp;if(!$sp){$b.='<br>';$sp=rand(3,5);}}}return $b;}

Comment: АХАХАХАХАХ

Answer (score 1):

```
$a='фовр. hasgdjashgd. dahsgdjahs ashdg aj. ashgjdag.  jashgdjashd.asdasd.asdasd.asd.as.d.';
```

Ну то что ты написал явно не сработает.

```
$rnd=rand(3,5);
$len=strlen($a);
$dot=0;
for (от 1 до $len)
смотри символ, если точка то 
условие если $dot=$rnd то добавить в строку "\n" и $dot=0;если еще не нужная нам точка то $dot++;
```

ну это если по простому.

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы не попробовать вот так

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $string = '
        Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", 
        часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.
        В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов.
        Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. 
        Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, 
        в более недавнее время,
        программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
        ';
        $arr = explode('.', $string);
        $iteration = rand(3,5);
        while ($iteration < count($arr)){
        $arr[$iteration] .= '<br>';
        $iteration += rand(3,5);
        }
        $text = implode('.', $arr);
        echo $text;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

зачем здесь regex?
split /./, затем цикл для замены и join.

Comment: надо не все точки переносить, а через 3-5, случайно.

Comment: Да все правильно. 
Только не split а explode().

Comment: ну и не нужно в цикле обрабатывать каждый элемент списка, а только то, что нужно по условию задачи.

Comment: я уже штук 20 вариантов накидал, но отчего-то я ищу однострочник.. в условиях не указал жаль.

Comment: однострочник??? удачи...

Comment: Мдям, куда катится нынешняя молодежь!